# Angular2 where is the AppComponent directive specified

Tags: angular

I am getting started with Angular2 and after having done the tutorial I got a question. It is said that `A browser ignores HTML tags and attributes that it doesn't recognize. So does Angular.` And that's why you have to add something like : `directives: [MyComponent]` inside a component if you want to use a tag you have created (like another component by instance).
Then my question is, why don't we need the same for the `AppComponent`. How does Angular knows about the `my-app` tag (selector of my `AppComponent`).

Is it thanks to the main.ts where there is a bootstrap of the AppComponent ? :

```
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With passing `AppComponent` to `bootstrap()` you make `AppComponent` known to Angular. `bootstrap()` then treats `AppComponent` like it was added to the `directives` of a parent component (which doesn't exist).

The root component is added by [`DynamicComponentLoader.loadAsRoot()`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html) that has the main purpose to instantiate the root component and add it to the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the way `bootstrap` works. The main HTML file isn't compiled unlike the component templates. So the main component is attached on an HTML element in this file using its selector.

> You instantiate an Angular application by explicitly specifying a component to use as the root component for your application via the bootstrap() method.
>
> An application is bootstrapped inside an existing browser DOM, typically index.html. Unlike Angular 1, Angular 2 does not compile/process providers in index.html. This is mainly for security reasons, as well as architectural changes in Angular 2. This means that index.html can safely be processed using server-side technologies such as providers.